# Rails 4 - Using MySQL2 gem getting "Table doesnt exist " error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2

Im trying to delete a table and truncate it using the following variations of code. All of the following versions give me the same error.

Code: 
        puts "Clearing Database Table: program_slots"
    ProgramSlot.destroy_all
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE program_slots")

```
   puts "Clearing Database Table: program_slots"
ProgramSlot.destroy_all
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE PROGRAMSLOTS")

    puts "Clearing Database Table: program_slots"
ProgramSlot.destroy_all
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE 'program_slots'")

    puts "Clearing Database Table: program_slots"
ProgramSlot.destroy_all
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE PROGRAM_SLOTS")
```

The table name is
        program_slots

The error Im getting is:

```
  >> ProgramSlot Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `program_slots`.* FROM `program_slots`

     (0.8ms)  TRUNCATE TABLE PROGRAMSLOTS

     Mysql2::Error: Table 'dd_development.programslots' doesn't exist: TRUNCATE TABLE PROGRAMSLOTS
```

Whats the right syntax? It seems that the underscore I put in my execute statement is not going through .......Notice the error statement is trying to find a table called "programslots" but the real table name is "program_slots".

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL table names are case sensitive, so that's why #1 and #3 fail. If you're going to use quotes then you need to use the correct ones for MySQL, which is why #2 fails.  I'm not sure why this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE program_slots")
```

wouldn't work.  If it doesn't, you can use this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE `program_slots`")
```

Note the angled single quotes.